# Allow access to customer data if user is part of privileged collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

The database structure is like so:

- suppliers(collection)>user_email(document)
- customers(collection)>user_email(document)>foo(field)

And the current firestore.rules is like so:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {

    //Base rule - fully restrictive
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    //Checks if user is registered in the suppliers section
    function isSupplierTeam(request) {
      return exists(/suppliers/$(request.auth.token.email));
    }

    // Supplier self-data access
    match /suppliers/{email} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.email == email;
    }
    match /suppliers/{email}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.email == email;
    }

    // Checking the Customer Sub-Section
    match /customers/{email} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.email == email || isSupplierTeam(request);
    }
    match /customers/{email}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.email == email || isSupplierTeam(request);
    }
}
```

And the query run in javascript, when logged in as a "supplier" is:

```
db.collection("customers").get()
.then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

    console.log(doc.id);
    console.log(doc.data());

  });
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
```

It doesn't seem to work and instead triggers a missing/insufficient permission error. How should I tweak my firestore.rules to allow suppliers to access the customer data?

Comment: Security rules are meaningless unless they are paired with specific queries and data that they are intended to allow.  Please edit the question to show the query that isn't working the way you expect, along with any relevant document data, and show clearly how the query is meeting the requirements of the rule that allows it.  We should be able to reproduce the scenario that you illustrate here.

Comment: Minor bug in your rules. Change all `if request.auth.token.email == email` to `if request.auth.token.email == $(email)` since the email you are referring to is the email in the doc path.

Comment: @PeterO. No, the name of the wildcard becomes a variable you can use like any other variable.  See the examples in the documentation for userId: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication

Comment: Yes, @DougStevenson, you are right. Ignore my first comment.

Comment: @DougStevenson

Good point, thanks. Added the query to the question.

Comment: [Security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  You can't simply make a query for all documents in the customers collection and get only the ones that match some criteria in your rules.  Firestore will not scan each and every document to see what matches - that will not scale for large collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this works:

```
//Checks if user is registered in the suppliers section
function isSupplierTeam(request) {
  return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/suppliers/$(request.auth.token.email));
}
```

It seems like the full "URL" is needed to access the relevant firestore document.